# Nested structured search is Sourcegraph?

Tags: regex, search, sourcegraph, comby

I would like to search Java annotations with another annotations inside. I don't know how many nested levels there are or I don't want to specify it. Finally, I would like to search for examples of `@ApiImplicitParams` with param type `body` and with `@Example` annotations inside.

But first I am trying to match anything nested.

First I searched for

```
@ApiImplicitParams(...)
```

and it [found me somethind](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global%20%40ApiImplicitParams%28...%29&patternType=structural). The very first result is

```
@ApiImplicitParams({ @ApiImplicitParam(name = "foo", value = "List of strings", paramType = "body", dataType = "Foo") })
```

and has `@ApiImplicitParam` inside. Let's try to match it.

I tried

```
@ApiImplicitParams({@ApiImplicitParam(...) ...})
```

but it didn't find that case with one nesting and didn't find any cases with multiple `@ApiImplicitParams` inside.

How to accomplish?

Comment: Let me check on this for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Finally, I would like to search for examples of @ApiImplicitParams with param type body and with @Example annotations inside.

I believe the following [query](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=context:global%20%40ApiImplicitParams%28%7B...%40ApiImplicitParam%28...paramType%20%3D%20%22body%22...%29...%7D%29%20lang:Java&patternType=structural) will meet your requirements here.
`@ApiImplicitParams({...@ApiImplicitParam(...paramType = "body"...)...}) lang:Java`

Some examples of matches --

```java
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiImplicitParams({ @ApiImplicitParam(name = "foo", value = "List of strings", paramType = "body", dataType = "Foo") })
    public Foo create(@RequestBody final Foo foo) {
```

```java
      nickname = "setLoggingSettings")
  @ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(
        name = "Logging Config",
        value = "Logging config to be updated",
        required = true,
        dataType = "com.yugabyte.yw.forms.PlatformLoggingConfig",
        paramType = "body")
  })
  public Result setLoggingSettings() throws JoranException {
```

A note on this --

> I don't know how many nested levels there are or I don't want to specify it.

The query provided above assumes one nested block, I'm afraid right now Sourcegraph doesn't have a good way to express an arbitrary level of nesting.

Hope that helps!